# Play framework 2.3 dist task - javascripts-min not available

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

My PlayFramework (2.3) application works without a problem when running it in the development mode (sbt run). However when I try to create distribution (sbt dist) or star production (sbt start), javascript files are searched in minification folder (javascripts-min) which is not available. On the other hand, if using sbt-uglify, it creates minified version of javascripts, but in the same directory (main.min.js and main.js).

```
GET http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts-min/main.js 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/main.js (Ok)
```

Probably I need to configure something to make minification happen. Should I include some sbt plugin or change application configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and for me the issue was that in the `.scala.html` file where I was loading the JavaScript file, I used `@helper.requireJs` like this:

```
@helper.requireJs(core = routes.Assets.at("javascripts/require.js").url,
  module = routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js").url)
```

Either `@helper.requireJs` is broken in Play Framework 2.3 or it's been deprecated, but it doesn't seem to work correctly any more. Replacing it with a regular `<script>` element solved the issue for me:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/require.js").url"
  data-main="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js").url"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use productionFolderPrefix parameter to specify the folder postfix, use "" if do not want one. (The parameter name is somewhat misleading though)

For example:

```
@helper.requireJs(core = routes.Assets.at("javascripts/require.js").url, 
  module = routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js").url, 
  productionFolderPrefix = "")
```

See [requireJs#apply() doc](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.requireJs$@apply(module:String,core:String,productionFolderPrefix:String,folder:String):play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable) or the [source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/requireJs.scala.html) for reference